# Fieldset validation data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have problem with fieldsets in ZF2, I show you my problem.

Here is my form (made by AngularJS, not by ZF2), where you can put a name, and select if you permit which page or which action (Pages are composed of actions).

[image: Form]

The picture below partially show what I send to ZF2 :

[image: Result]

Here is my data model of my CustomRole class :

```
class CustomRole
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users\CustomRolePagePermission", mappedBy="customRole")
     */
    protected $pagePermissions;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users\CustomRoleActionPermission", mappedBy="customRole")
     */
    protected $actionPermissions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users\GlobalRole")
     */
    protected $globalRole;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cie", inversedBy="customRoles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cie", referencedColumnName="id_cie")
     */
    protected $cie;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users\User", mappedBy="customRole")
     */
    protected $users;
...
```

Here my class CustomRolePagePermission (which is near the same than CustomRoleActionPermission) :

```
class CustomRolePagePermission extends PagePermission
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users\CustomRole", inversedBy="pagePermissions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="custom_role_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $customRole;
...
```

And then the abstract class PagePermission :

```
abstract class PagePermission
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Page")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $page;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $permission;
...
```

Now the Fieldset corresponding to CustomRole class (I have made it on each entities) :

```
class CustomRoleFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        parent::__construct('role');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager, 'App\Entity\Users\CustomRole'))
            ->setObject(new CustomRole());

        $this->add(array('name' => 'name'));

        $customRolePagePermissionFieldset = new CustomRolePagePermissionFieldset($entityManager);
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'pagePermission',
            'options' => array(
                'target_element' => $customRolePagePermissionFieldset
            ),
        ));

        $customRoleActionPermissionFieldset = new CustomRoleActionPermissionFieldset($entityManager);
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'actionPermission',
            'options' => array(
                'target_element' => $customRoleActionPermissionFieldset
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'name' => array('required' => true),
            'pagePermission' => array('required' => true),
            'actionPermission' => array('required' => true),
        );
    }
}
...
```

Here my fieldset CustomRolePagePermissionFieldset :

```
class CustomRolePagePermissionFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    protected $serviceManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager, 'App\Entity\Users\CustomRolePagePermission'))
            ->setObject(new CustomRolePagePermission());

        $this->add(array('name' => 'permission'));
    }
...
```

And then, my controller :

```
...
$customRoleForm = new CustomRoleForm($em);
$customRole = new CustomRole();
$formData = $request->getPost();
$customRoleForm->bind($customRole);
$customRoleForm->setData($formData);

if ($customRoleForm->isValid()) {
    $customRole->setCie($cie);
    $customRole->setGlobalRole($globalRole);
    $em->persist($customRole);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->ok($customRole->getId());
}
...
```

**Problem**

When I send the form, the CustomRole is created, but pages and actions checked previously are not linked with the CustomRole created, as if I had never checked any checkbox.

I don't understand why it doesn't have effects, do you have any ideas ?

Thanks a lot in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection should be "pagePermissions" for the hydrator to call setPagePermissions.